# Ajax call to php curl produce undefined

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, php-curl

Api: http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?formatted=true&lat=47.3&lng=9&username=sherazzi403&style=full

files: index.html - simple 2 input #lat for &lng= and #lng for &lng= and the button is for ajax to run the post request to the findnearbyplacename.php.

script.js: ajax post call with 2 data fields.

```js
  $('#btnRun').click(function() {

    // alert("Hello");
     lat = $('lat').val();
      lng = $('lng').val();
    $.ajax(
      {
        method: "POST",
        url: "libs/php/findnearbyplacename.php",
        data: {
          lat: $('#lat').val(),
          lng: $('#lng').val(),
        },
        success: function(result){
          console.log(result['data']);

          $('#div1').html(result['data'][0]['distance'])
        },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          // error code
          console.log("we have reached error ");
          console.log(lat, lng);

         }
      });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Find Nearby Place Names </title>
    <meta name="author" content="Hafizullah Karim" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="lat" name="lat">
    <input type="number" id="lng" name="lng">

    <button id="btnRun">Run</button>
    <br>
    <div id="div1"> </div>

    <script> console.log($('lat').val())</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

findnearbyplacename.php - php curl to get a json object from the api mentioned above.

full code here
https://github.com/Connector403/stage4/tree/master

```php
   <?php
$lat = $_REQUEST['lat'];
 $lng = $_REQUEST['lng'];
 $url = 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?formatted=true&lat'.$lat.'&lng='. $lng.'&username=sherazzi403&style=full';
 // initialize the resource
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 
 // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS)
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 
 curl_close($ch);
 // api returns data as json
 // decode the json as an associative array so that we can append it to the $output
 $decode = json_decode($result,true);

 // the 'geonames' properrty from the serialized JSON is store into the 'data'
 // element of $output
 $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
 // the correct header information for json is set and $output is converted to jsobn before send it
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
 echo json_encode ($output);
```

Comment: Are we suppose to guess what happens on the server side (like with your PHP?) Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Why does the code produce undefined in the console?

Comment: I am using xampp and when I run the code it only produces undefine undefined for the 2 inputs so what is causing this issue and how can i solve it?

Comment: To the undefined, ensure that you are using `#` with the jquery selectors to get the element id. The `data` section of the ajax has a stray `,` after the `lng` reference. (check the browser's console to check javascript errors, which coincidentally, the network tab there can be used to check the ajax requests too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems stem from a missing `=` in your `lat` parameter sent to the GeoNames API.

```
$url = 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?formatted=true&lat'.$lat.'&lng='. $lng.'&username=sherazzi403&style=full';
                                                                                ^ 
                                                                           = missing here
```

Using the Network tab of your browser's debugging tools you'll see that the response coming back from the API contains just a simple message: Missing parameter. Add the `=` and proper results come back.

Since you're not getting back the response you're expecting, the key you're looking for is absent, hence the `undefined` message. You should add some error checking here.

Also, as noted in the comments, you're missing a leading `#` on a couple of the jQuery calls but this isn't affecting the result because you have it correct where it matters.

There's also a trailing comma (`,`) in your `data` object, but that's not troubling Firefox.